# gl.Color affects the object has already been drawn between gl.Begin() and gl.End() in SharpGL?

Tags: c#, opengl

I'm learning SharpGL and there is a strange problem I can't understand, as far as I know when some object such as a cube is drawn by some `gl.Color` and `gl.Vertex` placed between `gl.Begin()` and `gl.End()` all other commands outside that pair of methods can't change the cube, but in my case it made some changes, more specifically, the gl.Color() called after the `gl.End()` (which ends the drawing of the cube) still be able to affect that cube, the cube was drawn with some texture binding.

Here is my code, I want to say that, this code was modified from an article in CodeProject, I'm not the original writer, but I modified it not to simply draw a rotating cube (as the code writer did) but a cube with a lip being able to be controlled (opened and closed using some keys), and I also want to draw a pyramid inside the cube, when closing the cube you can't see the pyramid and when pressing a key to open the cube's lip, it shows you the pyramid inside. That's very cute to me, this is a good beginning I've made before going deeper with the so-called OpenGL for C# (SharpGL):

```
private void openGLControl1_OpenGLDraw(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    // This is for pausing the scene
    if (pause) return;
    // Get the OpenGL object, for quick access.
    SharpGL.OpenGL gl = this.openGLControl1.OpenGL;

    // --------------------
    gl.Clear(OpenGL.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.Enable(OpenGL.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.LoadIdentity();
    gl.Translate(x, y, z);

    gl.Rotate(rtri, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    gl.BindTexture(OpenGL.TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // Start drawing the cube (or box)
    gl.Begin(OpenGL.QUADS);

    // Front Face
    gl.TexCoord(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1f);    // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(1,(float)2*Math.Cos(alpha)- 1, 1+(float)2*Math.Sin(alpha));    // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(-1,(float)2*Math.Cos(alpha) - 1, 1+(float)2*Math.Sin(alpha));    // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad

    // Back Face
    gl.TexCoord(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Texture

    // Top Face
    gl.TexCoord(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad

    // Bottom Face
    gl.TexCoord(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad

    // Right face
    gl.TexCoord(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad

    // Left Face
    gl.TexCoord(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);    // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    gl.TexCoord(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);    // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad

    // End drawing the box, but the code below still affect the cube? 
    // Why??? How to prevent this unexpected behavior?
    gl.End();

    // Increase The Rotation Variable For The Triangle
    rtri += 1.0f;// 0.2f;

    // This is my method to add controlling features to the box such as
    // moving up, down, left, right, near, far and opening, closing the
    // lip of the box, this is very simple and I think you don't need to care.
    ChangeCoord(null, EventArgs.Empty);

    // Try drawing a triangle in the box
    // Here is the starting point the strange thing comes, if I end this
    // method here, all will go well but if so I won't be able to create
    // a triangle inside the box.
    gl.Disable(OpenGL.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.LoadIdentity();
    gl.Translate(x, y, z - 0.5);
    gl.Scale(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
    gl.Rotate(r, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    gl.Begin(OpenGL.TRIANGLES);
    gl.Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(0f, 1f, 0f);
    gl.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(-1f, -1f, 1f);
    gl.Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(1f, -1f, 1f);

    gl.Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(0f, 1f, 0f);
    gl.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(1f, -1f, 1f);
    gl.Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(1f, -1f, -1f);

    gl.Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(0f, 1f, 0f);
    gl.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(1f, -1f, -1f);
    gl.Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(-1f, -1f, -1f);

    gl.Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(0f, 1f, 0f);
    gl.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); gl.Vertex(-1f, -1f, -1f);
    gl.Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); gl.Vertex(-1f, -1f, 1f);
    gl.End();

    r += 1.0f; //Just changing the rotating angle of the triangle.
}
```

The `gl.Color()`s which I think are used for drawing the triangle still affects the box?

I also downloaded another article in which the writer draws both a triangle and a cube in the same logic and all goes well but the cube in that code is drawn using `gl.Color()` without texture binding, in this code the cube is drawn with some texture from a Bitmap image.

Please help me out, the cube and triangle are drawn, I can control the cube as I want (move left, right, up, down, open and close the lip and pause the scene) but **the whole cube turns in blue overlapping the texture image, it's not I want**, because it doesn't look real, the texture image is enough. As I mentioned at the beginning, **if I don't use the code drawing the additional triangle, it will render well as I expect.**

Comment: One Off-Topic comment: Don't use the fixed function pipeline. The FFP is really old and you using something wich should not be used anymore. VertexBuffer and Shaders are the way to go.

Comment: really? Well, I'm totally new to SharpGL and haven't known about those things, as I mentioned in my question, almost of this code I copied from an artical in CodeProject, I didn't notice the posted time but I guess it is a little old. Thanks for the info...

Comment: @FelixK are you sure those things you talked about part of SharpGL not only OpenGL? Because I've tried searching those and didn't find any one of them, I'm using SharpGL v1.8, is it too old? Thanks!

Comment: SharpGL is not deprecated but the samples may be deprecated. The methods like `gl.TexCoord` are deprecated. It's a little more afford to use VertexBuffer and Shaders at the beginning but it's much faster and for some people which aren't using the FFP anymore ( like me ), it may be easier to help you. There are also some good tutorials for shaders and vertex buffers, just search for them on google ( VertexBuffers: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html ) and if you have any questions about theese techniques i would like to help you.

Comment: @KingKing: I made some modifications to make your code look nicer: it's not a good idea to put the comments at the end of the line, because this way we have to scroll right to see your comments. You should rather put them in front of the code line, and break these lines appropriately not to have to scroll right. And I think your question is too long, there is too much blah-blah (e.g. mentioning that it's not your source code, but not linking the original article, instead telling a story about that). I also think you should post a screenshot to make it clear what you would like to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you submit things to be drawn which require a colour, and you don't specify one, GL just uses the last colour you gave it.

If you don't even specify a colour, the default will be white.

Better to just give it the colour you want rather than relying on the right colour to be magically there when you need it.

Just put `gl.Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);` after your first `gl.Begin()`.

(And as others noted in your comments, the fixed-function pipeline is no longer recommended. Consider moving to the new programmable pipeline.)